# Accessing Ethereum network via JSON RPC from wallet balance/transactions

Tags: web3js, transactions, json-rpc, nodes, balances

sorry if the question is silly.... I am tying to build a simple app that checks ETH wallet addresses balances and transactions (for both ETH and Tokens).

As far as my knowledge goes, I think that I have two options:

- web3.js -> for which I need access to a node (hosted myself or by third party like infura.io)
- JSON RPC -> do I still need to access a node, or I can just "tap" into the network (a bit like ElectrumX nodes in Bitcoin?)

If I host a node (to be used with web3.js), does it need to be a "full node"? (that will be so big and so expensive (if i run in in AWS)

I have tried infura, but it does not seems to be reliable (requests time-out so frequently)

Any suggestion?

Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

Underneath web3.js uses JSON-RPC so both options are the same.

One other option is to run a light node it will only sync the most recent blocks, and forward more complex queries to a full node. For a light node to work it needs good connectivity and be able to connect to several full nodes.

I didn't have problems with infura, I think the have some kind of protection if you send too many requests.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion... I will look into that.. but what I am trying to avoid is to install a "full node" in my infrastructure... (because in my case infura was not that great)

My hypothesis was to try to interact to a "public node" like you can do with in Bitcoin (using Electrum nodes and JSON RPC calls)...

Does Ethereum have a "public node infrastructure" or the only option is "infura"?

Comment: Probably the closest thing is running a light node.

Comment: thank you @ismael, where can I find info for light node (installation/specks/ storage requirements/network requirements etc.)? I simply need to find addresses balances and relative transactions (both ETH, and tokens)... does a light node handle this type of requests?

Answer (score 1):

You need a node to connect to in any case. There are some alternatives to Infura like [Chainstack](https://chainstack.com) or [QuikNode](https://quiknode.io) that you can consider.